# How do I proper use GetStreamFilter from Python-Twitter library?

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, python-twitter

I've been having some troubles using the `GetStreamFilter` function from the [Python-Twitter library](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter%5d).

I have used this code:

```
import twitter
import time

consumer_key = 'myConsumerKey'
consumer_secret = 'myConsumerSecret'
access_token = 'myAccessToken'
access_token_secret = 'myAccessTokenSecret'

apiTest = twitter.Api(consumer_key,
                      consumer_secret,
                      access_token,
                      access_token_secret)

#print(apiTest.VerifyCredentials())

while (True):
    stream = apiTest.GetStreamFilter(None, ['someWord'])
    try:
        print(stream.next())
    except:
        print ("No posts")

    time.sleep(3)
```

What I want to do is to fetch new tweets that include the word "someWord", and to do these every three seconds (or every time there's a new one that is published).

Comment: What error or output is occurring?

Comment: It just stay forever in the stream.next(). No error. I guess I am using it wrong, that is why I wonder if anyone knows how to do it right. I tried then tweepy (another library) which is more easy to use and it worked after some effort, but I would prefer to stay with python-twitter due to its other functions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the stream only once and outside the loop.

```
stream = apiTest.GetStreamFilter(None, ['someWord'])

while True:
    for tweet in stream:
        print(tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing your `while True` with a loop that extracts things out of the stream?

```
for tweet in apiTest.GetStreamFilter(track=['someWord']):
    print tweet
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I finally finish using the Tweepy library.